# How to inhibit "Loud music may harm your hearing..." warning in Android

Tags: android

I have an Android application for a Samsung tablet that uses an external device which draws its power from the tablet headphone jack.  When the external device is powered on (by programmatically maxing out the volume), Android briefly displays a warning popup saying: "Loud music may harm your hearing if you listen to it for too long..."  I would like that message to not be displayed.

Here's the offending line of code:

```
mAudioMgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioMgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
```

It's not an option to only turn it up halfway.  In fact, I've seen the tablet display the warning (when changing the volume by hand) even on volume settings lower than the max setting.

And yes, I record the original volume, and restore it when we're done with the external device.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Does this happen with other tablets? I believe this is something specific to Samsung tablets (or possibly just the one). I've never seen it on any of my devices.

Comment: @Tanis.7x - I'm not sure about other tablets.  We chose this one since it is certified by the manufacturer of the external device.

Comment: It happens on my Nexus 7 as well.  It's a feature of Android for external speakers since most are headphones.

Comment: Just a general note - the tablet has 16 volume settings, plus mute.  The warning is displayed not just on the highest (16) level, but whenever you hit at least 14.

Comment: Another general note to save others the hassle - I downloaded the Android open source codebase, and searched for this error message - it isn't there.  My hope was that I could find it, then find where it is used and change that, or override the string (so the toast popup just displays a very small empty box or something).  But, no joy.

Comment: Welcome to 2013. Yep, we're still using hacky hardware solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot disable the systems message, and you will also have a problem when the user manually lowers the volume, I suggest you do a series of controls which will help with that.
To max the volume:

```
public void maxVolume() {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    while ( audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) < audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)) {
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
    }
}
```

To prevent users from manually changing volume:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
         || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
         || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can call maxVolume() in your onCreate method, and later call it just before you start using the jack output procedure to make sure the system has not changed your volume.
Alternatively you can register a listener to listen for volume changes, make maxVolume() static and call it from the listener. Hope it helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is quite old, but I just ran across this issue myself. I figured that I would add to the answers given with what I found in case it helps someone else that happens upon this.

One of the posts here mentions that the warning is not in the AOSP, but this is not true. Please reference the VolumePanel::SafteyWarning class here: [VolumePanel::SafetyWarning](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/com/android/systemui/volume/VolumePanel.java#VolumePanel.SafetyWarning)

Once you peruse through the SafetyWarning class you'll notice that there is a hidden method inside of the AudioManager class called **disableSafeMediaVolume**. You can, through reflection, invoke this hidden method easily enough, but if you do then you'll get a security exception as it requires the system permission "android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE".

So... with that said, the dialog as far as I can tell, cannot be programmatically suppressed unless you have this system permission.

What we ended up doing with the blessing of product management is we cache the volume setting in SharedPreferences and then reset it from the cache when our application starts. If it happens to be above the threshold for the warning dialog then the warning will be shown and the user will just have to press OK to get the volume setting that they want, but at least they won't have to manually reset the volume themselves.

A couple of other notes on why some don't see this dialog. You will only see it if you have headphones (or earbuds, or a wired headset) plugged into the device and you attempt to set the media volume stream over a certain threshold (on the Samsung Galaxy Tab A this threshold is 60%). If you press OK at the dialog then it will not be shown again unless you either restart the device or unplug the headphones and plug them back in (with the volume set at or above the threshold).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The method does not require permissions for Android 4.2 through 4.4; but it does for 5.0+. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can consider this much of an answer but I'm pretty sure you can't remove that message as its displayed by the system automatically and not by something you can access. My Samsung Galaxy S3 does the same thing.

Also from what I can read on the net some android devices also lower the volume when you put in a jack stick so "you don't harm your hearing".

Can you override the notification by displaying your own notification just before or after perhaps? The notification is just a standard `Toast`.

Comment: We noticed that tapping anywhere on the screen makes the warning disappear, so what we're playing with now is to activate the external device (by setting the volume to max), and then either bringing our activity to the foreground, or simulating a screen tap.

Comment: @MikeHedman and I believe a haxxy thing like that is the only workaround for this issue of your.

Comment: @MikeHedman I just wanted to add an extra comment. Any haxxy workaround can be expected to change due to new android releases and may also wary depending on phone manufacture and version.